# How many are the anagrams of the word MISSISSIPPI in which there are no two consecutive I letters?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Can anyone give me a complementary approach to this problem? That is, the calculation of the total minus the "unwanted". Answer: 1050

Comment: Are you certain that there is only one P in there?

Comment: Yes. It's almost a trap of the problem. :)

Comment: My elementary school ditty begs to differ with your spelling

Answer (score 2):

You can linearly arrange the $7$ non-Is in
$${7!\over 4!\cdot2!}=105$$
ways. The generated $7$-letter word has $8$ spaces (inclusive the ends). You can choose $4$ of these spaces for an I in
$${8\choose4}=70$$
ways. The total number of admissible $11$-letter words therefore is $105\cdot70=7350$.